# ILookup access value or How to Multimap Dictionary

Tags: c#

i have multiple values for one key and caused by this I cannot use my dictionary, therefore I found the ILookup, but I have now two problems.

1. I cannot access by my Classmembername the value in my ILookup. Is it possible like a dictionary?
2. Is it possible to have to Index? I need one index(key) the name and as secondary the Location.

If somebody has a better idea or can guide me

My XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <customers>
  <cust ID="1" DeviceID="1" Name="Bob" Location="Home" Latitude="10" Longitude="58" Device="HW1.0"> </cust>
  <cust ID="2" DeviceID="2" Name="Jack" Location="Home" Latitude="28" Longitude="20" Device="HW2.2"> </cust>
  <cust ID="2" DeviceID="3" Name="Jack" Location="Home" Latitude="40" Longitude="40" Device="HW2.3"> </cust>
  <cust ID="2" DeviceID="4" Name="Jack" Location="Office" Latitude="40" Longitude="40" Device="HW2.3"> </cust>
  <cust ID="2" DeviceID="5" Name="Jack" Location="Office" Latitude="40" Longitude="40" Device="HW2.4"> </cust>
  </customers>
```

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace DictHelp
{
    class Customer
    {
        public string Location;
        public int DeviceID;
        public int Longitude;
        public int Latitude;
        public string Device;
    }
    class Program
    {
         private static ILookup<string, Customer> ReadXmlToLookup()
        {
            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

            var XDoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\ADB\test.xml");

            var MyLookup =
            XDoc.Root
            .Elements("cust")
            .ToLookup(xe =>
                            xe.Attribute("Name").Value,
                            xe =>
                            new Customer
                            {
                                DeviceID = (int)xe.Attribute("DeviceID"),
                                Longitude = (int)xe.Attribute("Longitude"),
                                Latitude = (int)xe.Attribute("Latitude"),
                                Device = (string)xe.Attribute("Device")
                            });

            return MyLookup;

        }




        private static Dictionary<string, Customer> ReadXmlToDictionary(string filename)
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, Customer>();

            var XDoc = XDocument.Load(@"D:\ADB\test.xml");

            var customersDictionary =
            XDoc.Root
            .Elements("cust")
            .ToDictionary(xe =>
                            xe.Attribute("Name").Value, xe =>
                            new Customer
                            {
                                DeviceID = (int)xe.Attribute("DeviceID"),
                                Longitude = (int)xe.Attribute("Longitude"),
                                Latitude = (int)xe.Attribute("Latitude"),
                                Device = (string)xe.Attribute("Device")
                            });
            return dict;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dict = ReadXmlToDictionary(null); // not possible multiple same keys
            string name = "Bob";
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", dict[name].Longitude.ToString(), dict[name].Latitude.ToString());
            var look = ReadXmlToLookup();
            look[name]. // Cannot access the value by class name**

            int i = 0;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot access the value by class name"? It would help if you'd remove the XML part from the question, as it's not really relevant. Just show a short but *complete* example. It's not clear what you're trying to do with `look[name]` - but you need to bear in mind that it will be a *sequence* of `Customer` references, not a single one. That's almost certainly what's tripping you up, but it's hard to know when we don't know what you're trying to do with it.